# Adding list to the JSON file with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to add list of tags to the JSON but I'm getting simple property rather than list.

Initial JSON file

```
{
  "Name": "Job1",
  "Tasks": []
}
```

I would like to add new object to to the list of Tasks and this object has to have list of tags

```
$json = Get-Content .\def.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$task = @{"TaskName"="New task";"Tags" = @('R2.0','R2.1')}
$json.Tasks += $task
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

and result of this is

```
{
    "Name":  "Job1",
    "Tasks":  [
                  {
                      "TaskName":  "New task",
                      "Tags":  "R2.0 R2.1"
                  }
              ]
}
```

but it should be

```
{
    "Name":  "Job1",
    "Tasks":  [
                  {
                      "TaskName":  "New task",
                      "Tags": [
                                   "R2.0",
                                   "R2.1"
                              ]
                  }
              ]
}
```

I have tried to defined different types of variables and every time it the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the `Depth` parameter to `ConvertTo-Json`.

```
$json = @"
{
  "Name": "Job1",
  "Tasks": []
}
"@

$obj = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$newObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    TaskName = "New Task"
    Tags = @("R2.0", "R2.1")
}

$obj.Tasks += $newObject

$obj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Result:

```
{
    "Name":  "Job1",
    "Tasks":  [
                  {
                      "TaskName":  "New Task",
                      "Tags":  [
                                   "R2.0",
                                   "R2.1"
                               ]
                  }
              ]
}
```